# can't deploy ASP.net application on windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having problem in deploying my ASP.Net application on the windows Server 2012,it works correctly in local not in the server,this is the error that I get:

[image]

so please how can I solve this error,I don't know why I get it 
thanks for help

Update:
I get now this error:

GET http://localhost/home/home 404 (Not Found)  angular.js:8513
but how it works locally not in the server :(

Comment: Have you installed MVC on the server (or shipped the assemblies as part of your deployment?)

Comment: I did a Publish, right click on my project in Solution Explorer and select 'Publish'. Basically it will compile my solution and dump all the assemblies/artifacts

Answer (score 1):

Your files are not under the proper folder that's why it is not found

I recommend using an absolute URL:

```
<link href="/RetailSmart/Jquery/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Sorry Sir but I didn't understand your reply where can I find this file?

Comment: Look out that error , right side you see a url where the page have the problem. You need to open the page and see, any where you looking for resources, and what is the url, something like i posted above, and see that url mentioned is correct, actually that particular resource should exist there.else this error occurs.